# it is possible to reverse the container BorderRadius in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, containers

i am trying to make layout like this

[image]

i need the bottomRight corner at other side ..

i tried this but it does not work

```
 Container(
                  width: 200
                    height: 200
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: 
                        Radius.circular(40),),),
                      color:  Colors.deepPurple[900]!,
                    ),

                  ),
```

does it possible in flutter frame work ?

Comment: Custom Clippath is your looking for but if you want something you don't need to to do the numbers for each sides. Try a package called **flutter_custom_clippers** and try the SideCutClipper and explore or play with it

Comment: thanks , but this package does not offer the wanted layout since i have seen this package before

Comment: Does the layout below is circle? or a look like a bite?

Comment: circle Exactly ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this [`ClipPath`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html)

**For left corner**

```dart
class CustomCornerClipPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final double cornerR;
  const CustomCornerClipPath({this.cornerR = 16.0});

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) => Path()
    ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
    ..lineTo(
      size.width,
      size.height - cornerR,
    )
    ..arcToPoint(
      Offset(
        size.width - cornerR,
        size.height,
      ),
      radius: Radius.circular(cornerR),
      clockwise: false,
    )
    ..lineTo(0, size.height);

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

And use

```dart
ClipPath(
  clipper: const CustomCornerClipPath(),
  child: Container(
    height: 100, //based on your need
    width: 100,
    color: Colors.cyanAccent,
  ),
),
```

[image]

---

**For the right corner,** path will be

```dart
@override
Path getClip(Size size) => Path()
  ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
  ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
  ..lineTo(cornerR, size.height)
  ..arcToPoint(
    Offset(
      0,
      size.height - cornerR,
    ),
    radius: Radius.circular(cornerR),
    clockwise: false,
  );
```

[image]

I will recommend visiting [cliprrect-clippath-in-flutter](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/cliprrect-clippath-in-flutter-4c41abe4e8?gi=e73c9564b7c1)

Comment: thanks that's what we got from experience but the wanted  BorderRadius is 40 , is it possible ?

Comment: you can pass than using `cornerR`

Comment: can you please edit the answer to make corner in the bottom left and not bottom right, i spent 3 hours trying to handle this but could not , thanks

Comment: glad to help out, play with `Path` there are other method can be used.